# Error while changing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, xmlnode

I am trying to change a XML file in code. I have found some good examples online and tried to do the same but it doesn't work. When I try my code with a simple XML document there are no errors but with my XML document I get this error :

> `Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.`

This is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ns2:VATConsignment xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment" VATDeclarationsNbr="@aantal_aangiftes@">
    <ns2:VATDeclaration SequenceNumber="@aangifte_nr@">
<ns2:Declarant>
            <VATNumber>@firma_btw@</VATNumber>
            <Name>@firma_naam@</Name>
            <Street>@firma_straat@</Street>
            <PostCode>@firma_pnr@</PostCode>
            <City>@firma_wpl@</City>
            <CountryCode>BE</CountryCode>
            <EmailAddress>@firma_email@</EmailAddress>
            <Phone>@firma_tel@</Phone>
        </ns2:Declarant>
<ns2:Period>
            <ns2:Month>@maand@</ns2:Month>
            <ns2:Quarter>@kwart@</ns2:Quarter>
            <ns2:Year>@jaar@</ns2:Year>
        </ns2:Period>
<ns2:Data>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="0">@VAK0@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="1">@VAK1@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="2">@VAK2@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="3">@VAK3@</ns2:Amount>

            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="44">@VAK44@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="45">@VAK45@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="46">@VAK46@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="47">@VAK47@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="48">@VAK48@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="49">@VAK49@</ns2:Amount>

            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="54">@VAK54@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="55">@VAK55@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="56">@VAK56@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="57">@VAK57@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="59">@VAK59@</ns2:Amount>

            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="61">@VAK61@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="62">@VAK62@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="63">@VAK63@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="64">@VAK64@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="65">@VAK65@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="66">@VAK66@</ns2:Amount>

            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="71">@VAK71@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="72">@VAK72@</ns2:Amount>

            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="81">@VAK81@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="82">@VAK82@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="83">@VAK83@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="84">@VAK84@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="85">@VAK85@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="86">@VAK86@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="87">@VAK87@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="88">@VAK88@</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:Amount GridNumber="91">@VAK91@</ns2:Amount>
        </ns2:Data>
<ns2:ClientListingNihil>@nihil_listing@</ns2:ClientListingNihil>
        <ns2:Ask Payment="NO" Restitution="NO"/>
        <ns2:Comment>@commentaar@</ns2:Comment>
    </ns2:VATDeclaration>
</ns2:VATConsignment>
```

And this is my code i have written :

```
        XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
        doc2.Load(@"C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\xsd\TemplateAangifte.xml");

        XmlNode aangeverNode = doc2.SelectSingleNode(@"/ns2:VATConsignment/ns2:VATDeclaration/ns2:Declarant");
```

The error gets triggered when trying to load the `XmlNode`.
I am pretty new to the XML story so every help is welcome !

Thanks !

Kevin

Comment: I have added a namespacemanager but now I get the error that Namespace prefix 'ns2' is not defined.
                XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            doc2.Load(@"C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\xsd\TemplateAangifte.xml");

            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc2.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

             XmlNode aangeverNode = doc2.SelectSingleNode(@"/ns2:VATConsignment/ns2:VATDeclaration/ns2:Declarant", nsmgr);

Comment: It's undefined because it was not declared. You don't need an `xsl` namespace. You need `nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment");`. The original prefix is irrelevant. You could use any other prefix as long as the namespace is correct: `nsmgr.AddNamespace("vc", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment");` and `"/vc:VATConsignment/vc:VATDeclaration/vc:Declarant"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the namespace manager mapping each namespace that is declared in your XML source file *and that you use* in your XPath expression with a prefix. *The prefix that you declare in the mapping should be used in your XPath selectors.* The prefix need not be the same as the one used in the source file (it *may* be the same as the original prefix, but it doesn't have to be).

Here are the declarations you need to add if you want to access *any element* from your source file:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc2.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment");

// Not necessary unless you decide to use an unprefixed element from your source
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon");
```

To access an unprefixed element, you would use `ns0:EmailAddress` for example.

Comment: Thanks @helderdarocha ! Will give it a try ! Edit : Works perfectly ! Thanks you !!

Comment: I have one question left how do I access my attribute like the VATDeclarationsNbr or the SequenceNumber ?

Comment: Use `@SequenceNumber`. For example: `/ns2:VATConsignment/ns2:VATDeclaration/@SequenceNumber`. There are many other ways you can select nodes. You can select the string "@VAK44@" for example, using a predicate expression such as `//ns2:Amount[@GridNumber="44"]`. Search for an XPath reference for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info i solved it this way : doc2.SelectSingleNode("/ns2:VATConsignment", nsmgr).Attributes["VATDeclarationsNbr"].InnerText =

Comment: one last question : I want to alter the value of Amount where the attribute gridNumber is 3 (<ns2:Amount GridNumber="3">@VAK3@</ns2:Amount> ) how can i acces this value?

Comment: XmlNode vak1 = doc2.SelectSingleNode("/ns2:VATConsignment/ns2:VATDeclaration/ns2:Data/ns2:Amount[@GridNumber='1']", nsmgr);

Comment: You can *access* (read the data) in the element using that. You can also use that to generate a new XML file and overwrite the original one, if possible. The XPath tools you are using (`SelectSingleNode`) don't *alter* anything. If you need to transform the data in one or more places and generate a new XML file, you might consider writing an XSLT stylesheet and the `XslTransform` class. XSLT uses XPath to *select* (read) data but also allows you to create templates which generate a transformed result document.